# Building JShortcut JNI dll

Tags: netbeans, compilation, jshortcut

I'm trying to build the JShortcut dll for x64 based the source found in Github :
https://github.com/jimmc/jshortcut/

I cloned the repository, followed the Make instructions. But I have trouble with following action:

> You can build everything except for the DLL on
>   any machine with Java and GNU make.  ***You can build the DLL
>   separately on a Windows machine by running the compile.bat script*** in
>   the src/jni directory.  Do this just after doing the "make all" in the
>   sequence below.

This file is :

```
cl "-IC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/include" "-IC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/include/win32" -LD jshortcut.cpp -Fejshortcut_amd64.dll Advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib
```

And `cl` is not recognized. I don't know what to do. I'm using Apache Netbeans 12 with cpp support. So I guess I should be able to do this from Netbeans, but I'm not familiar at all with cpp.

**[Edit]**

I replaced :

- `cl` by `gcc` (after FoggyDay suggestion) and
- all the `.lib` by their `.dll` counterpart ,

I've got now:

`gcc "-IC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/include" "-IC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/include/win32" -LD jshortcut.cpp -Fejshortcut_amd64.dll /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Advapi32.dll /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/shell32.dll /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/ole32.dll`

The compilation gives me the following error:

```
gdrive/z/Temp/ccdePcoW.o:jshortcut.cpp:(.xdata$_ZN7JNIEnv_9NewObjectEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz+0xc): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
gdrive/z/Temp/ccdePcoW.o:jshortcut.cpp:(.xdata$_ZN7JNIEnv_9NewObjectEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz+0xc): relocation truncated to fit: rva32 against undefined symbo
__gxx_personality_seh0'
r/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/z/Temp/ccdePcoW.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata$_ZN7JNIEnv_9NewOb
tEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz'
lect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is a similar error [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386323/how-to-add-an-external-library-in-c-using-cygwin), but I have not enough knowledge to apply this here. The [jshortcut.cpp file can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/jimmc/jshortcut/blob/master/src/jni/jshortcut.cpp).

Comment: "cl" is the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.  Try changing your makefile to "gcc" or "g++", if you're using Gnu C/C++

Comment: Thanks. I've moved one step further. Having some compilation issues now.

Comment: This means you *must* compile with `g++`.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/203550/3135317

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined Symbol \_\_\_gxx\_personality\_v0 on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203548/undefined-symbol-gxx-personality-v0-on-link)